colab-error: subprocess-exited-with-error
!pip install ecco
This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Downloading scikit-learn-0.23.2.tar.gz (7.2 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.2/7.2 MB 39.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Collecting ecco
Using cached ecco-0.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (70 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: transformers~=4.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ecco) (4.38.2)
Requirement already satisfied: seaborn~=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ecco) (0.13.1)
Collecting scikit-learn~=0.23 (from ecco)
Using cached scikit-learn-0.24.2.tar.gz (7.5 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
I tried to execute codes below, but it does not work out. How can I deal with it?
!pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
!pip install ecco

I tried to execute: !pip3 install wheel setuptools pip , but it failed.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
